# imagecreatefromjpeg($filename) not work

Tags: php, image

I'm new to PHP and I'm using Apache to run my PHP file and it work fine all the time. However, when I learnt captcha image generate today and try to build one by my own, I have I can't make one because the `imagecreatefromjpeg($filename)` function did not provide any output.

I have follow the tutorial of output an image from youtube.com but it not work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2hQsFoBSiM&t=255s

When I follow the exactly same code from video, it show below picture.

[image]

And I got some answers about extension of PHP, and I have tried to enable like below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
session_start();

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$randomstr = md5(microtime());

$randomstr = substr($randomstr,0,5);

$bgimg =imagecreatefromjpeg("./img/img.jpg");

$linecolor = imagecolorallocate($bgimg,255,255,255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($bgimg,0,255,255);

imageline($bgimg,1,0,140,80,$linecolor);
imageline($bgimg,1,100,120,0,$linecolor); 

imagestring($bgimg, 5, 50, 30, $randomstr, $textcolor);// 

$_SESSION['captcha'] = $randomstr;

imagejpeg($bgimg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print `$bgimg =imagecreatefromjpeg("./img/img.jpg");`

```
print($bgimg);
```

If it does not show any result It means it does not read your directory.

Try double dot:

```
$bgimg =imagecreatefromjpeg("../img/img.jpg");
```

or try to view page source.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Arvin. However, it still not work. I'm using Bracket to edit my code, and when I put my cursor on the "./img/img.jpg", it would show the image. I believe that mean the directory is correct.